# How to compile\publish ActionSctipt and .FLA as a .SWF

Tags: actionscript, flash, flash-cs5

I have very little experience with Flash but I need to edit an existing group of ActionScript and FLA and export it as a SWF file.

I have Flash Professional installed.
I am a .NET/Java developer, so the coding is not an issue.

The issue is I don't know how to "open" the source code as a "project" fit for "publication".

The program I want to edit is an open source quiz on OnGaurdOnline.gov:
Web - http://www.onguardonline.gov/media/game-0011-phishing-scams
Download - http://www.onguardonline.gov/sites/default/files/phishing_game_source.zip

What do I have to do in order to:
1)Open the "project" (Right now its a folder of .as, .fla and .swf files)
2) Makes changes to code (how do I open the script window)
3) "Publish" the changes so that the same output is created (2 SWF files; loader.swf, phishing.swf)

I would really appreciate any assistance you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.- Open the fla file (project are no available in Flash CC)
2.- Press F9 to apen the "Action Window"  or go to   Window > Action
3.- change your code
4.- Pres CTRL + INTRO to test your changes
5.- Publish Shift + ALT + F12 to compile
```